# How can I pass a monadic function as an argument with a flexible type variable?

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, rank-n-types

Apologies for the potentially vague question title - I'm not sure how to phrase it because I have a pretty poor understanding of what the problem is.

Basically, how do I make the following compile? :-p

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class (Monad m) => MyClass m a where
  valM :: m (Maybe a)
  val  :: m a

f :: (MyClass m a) => (m a -> IO a) -> IO (a, Maybe a)
f g = do
  x <- g val
  yM <- g valM
  return (x, yM)
```

GHC (v8.2.2) complains that `a` is a rigid type variable and can't seem to cope with the idea that `(g val)` and `(g valM)` could produce values of different types.  I've tried using `RankNTypes` but to no avail.

Is there an extension I can use to help the compiler, or is there something conceptually broken with what I'm trying to do from a type-inference point of view?

Comment: Completely orthogonal to the question, but `f` is more elegantly written `f g = liftA2 (,) (g val) (g valM)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re right that you need `RankNTypes`, but you’re missing a `forall`. The correct type for `f` is:

```
f :: MyClass m a => (forall b. m b -> IO b) -> IO (a, Maybe a)
```

…since the function passed to `f` must work for any result type, and it shouldn’t be related to the `a` in the result.

---

It’s also potentially worth noting that this sort of function is also known as a *natural transformation*, and the natural-transformation package provides [a `(~>)` type alias](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/natural-transformation-0.4/docs/Control-Natural.html#t:-126--62-) for such functions:

```
type (~>) f g = forall a. f a -> g a
```

Therefore, using that type alias, you could also write `f` like this:

```
f :: MyClass m a => (m ~> IO) -> IO (a, Maybe a)
```

Comment: Ah the key thing I was missing was that I didn't realise you could use the ```forall``` syntax on the right hand side of ```=>```.  That's great, thanks for your help!

Comment: @johncowie That is, in fact, precisely what `RankNTypes` allows. Consider reading [the relevant section of the GHC user’s guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#arbitrary-rank-polymorphism).